# Using regex to parse financial statements

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm working on a regex query to return texts of a particular pattern into groups. Here is the regex that I've used: `r"([\w+ \-? \w+]* [\w+ ]+ [\(?\w+ \)?]*) (\(?[\d,-]+\)?) (\(?[\d,-]+\)?)"`. Here are the sample lines that I'm parsing and what I'd like the output to be:

```
1) String: LOSS BEFORE INCOME TAXES (900,000) (900,000)
Desired output: [('LOSS BEFORE INCOME TAXES', '(900,000)', '(900,000)')]
Final result: correct 

2) String: INCOME TAXES (RECOVERED) (90,000) (90,000)
Desired output: [('INCOME TAXES (RECOVERED)', '(90,000)', '(90,000)')]
Final result: correct

3) String: RETAINED EARNINGS - BEGINNING OF YEAR 9,999,999 9,999,999
Desired output: [('RETAINED EARNINGS - BEGINNING OF YEAR', '9,999,999', '9,999,999')]
Final result: correct

4) String: EXPENSES
Desired output: ['EXPENSES']
Final result: correct

5) String: Subcontracts 8,058 2,655
Desired output: [('Subcontracts', '8,000,000')]
Final result: ['Subcontracts 8', '', '058 2', '', '655', '']

6) String: Business taxes 116 -
Desired output: [('Business taxes', '116', '-')]
Final result: ['Business taxes 116 ', '', '']

7) String: 600,000 600,000
Desired output: [(600,000), (600,000)]
Final result: ['642', '', '437 629', '', '070', '']

8) String: Salaries, wages and benefits 400,000 400,000
Desired output: [('Salaries, wages and benefits', '400,000', '400,000')]
Final result: [(' wages and benefits', '463,437', '466,742')]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing, but 5, 6, 7 & 8 have problems with them. How can I adjust the above query such that it accounts for all the mentioned cases? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See regex101, the strings 5-7 don't appear to be matching at all: https://regex101.com/r/7DNqu9/1 Your character sets don't make sense, a character set should contain each character you want to include in the set *only once* (eg `[\w+ \-? \w+]` means "a word character, or a plus, or a space, or a dash, or a question mark. It's not clear what exactly you want the logic to be for the first group

Comment: All but #4 - `r'(([^0-9]+) )?([0-9(),]+) ([0-9(),]+)?'` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex will do what you want:

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9 (),%;-]+?[^(\d\s])? ?(?:(\(?[\d,]+\)?|-)\s+(\(?[\d,]+\)?|-))?$
```

It looks for a set of alphabetic characters, starting with a letter, and possibly including some of `[(),%;-]`, but not ending with a `(`, digit or whitespace, followed by two groups of possibly `()` surrounded digits and `,` or `-`. All groups are optional to allow matching lines with no description or no numbers.

In Python:

```
import re
data = """LOSS BEFORE INCOME TAXES (900,000) (900,000)
INCOME TAXES (RECOVERED) (90,000) (90,000)
RETAINED EARNINGS - BEGINNING OF YEAR 9,999,999 9,999,999
EXPENSES
Subcontracts 8,058 2,655
Business taxes 116 -
600,000 600,000
GROSS PROFIT (50%; 2016 - 50%) 500,000 500,000
Bad debts - 50
Salaries, wages and benefits 400,000 400,000"""
regex = re.compile('^([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9 (),%;-]+?[^(\d\s])? ?(?:(\(?[\d,]+\)?|-)\s+(\(?[\d,]+\)?|-))?$', re.MULTILINE)
print regex.findall(data)
```

Output:

```
[('LOSS BEFORE INCOME TAXES', '(900,000)', '(900,000)'),
 ('INCOME TAXES (RECOVERED)', '(90,000)', '(90,000)'),
 ('RETAINED EARNINGS - BEGINNING OF YEAR', '9,999,999', '9,999,999'),
 ('EXPENSES', '', ''),
 ('Subcontracts', '8,058', '2,655'),
 ('Business taxes', '116', '-'),
 ('', '600,000', '600,000'),
 ('GROSS PROFIT (50%; 2016 - 50%)', '500,000', '500,000'),
 ('Bad debts', '-', '50'),
 ('Salaries, wages and benefits', '400,000', '400,000')
]
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/DWD62077)

Comment: This is great. If these cases show: `GROSS PROFIT (50%; 2016 - 50%) 500,000 500,000` AND `Bad debts - 50`

Your query produces: 

`[('GROSS PROFIT', '(47', '')]` rather than `[('GROSS PROFIT (50%; 2016 - 50%)', ' 500,000', ' 500,000')]`
 
`[('Bad debts -', '34', '')]` rather than `[('Bad debts', '-', '34')]`

How can I change your query to account for those 2 as well

Comment: @Sam I'll need to think about them as they're (especially the first one) quite different from the original question. You should add them to your question and unaccept the answer in case you can get a better one.

Comment: @Sam see my edit. It fixes the two cases you mentioned and hopefully is robust enough to deal with other weird and wonderful lines!

Comment: Thank you so much nick! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this mate**

```
^([a-z, \(\)-]*?)?\(?([\d,]+)?\)?\s*?\(?([\d,-]+)?\)?$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `([a-z, \(\)-]+?)?` - Matches any character a to z, or `,` or `(` or ')` or '-' zero or more time (lazy mode).
- `\(?` - Matches `(` (`?` makes it optional).
- ([\d,]+)? - Matches any digit or `,` one or more time.(`?` makes it optional).
- `\)` - Matches `)`.
- `\s*?` - Matches space zero or more time.
- `(?([\d,-]+)?\)?` - Matches any digit or `-`.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vjEGh7/2/)

Comment: i dont think this is correct, if u turn off case insensitive plag its not matching it

Comment: @RishiBansal Well better look at the question first.alphabets are not in any single case.Why one will turn off case insensitive flag ?

Answer (score -1):

Try below regex

```
r"([\w ,()-]*)[\(?[\d, -]*\)?]*[\(?[\d, -]*\)?]*"
```

Comment: @Certain what you say about this one. However i understand last time it was too generic i think thats what you mean.

Comment: Makes more sense, but it doesn't capture any of the groups OP was looking for: https://regex101.com/r/7DNqu9/3

Comment: my bad, included "(" ")" as well

Comment: You can just plug your tests into the regex101 link to see how they do: https://regex101.com/r/7DNqu9/4 None of the groups OP is looking for are being captured